# How to figure out how a popup URL is derived in chrome devtools?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, popup, google-chrome-devtools

https://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/govi/pharmaz/2012/00000067/00000002/art00012

I am trying to learn how to resolve the PDF download link after clicking "Download" on the above webpage in chrome devtools. Because the popup windows is started automatically, I use the following command to automatically open the devtools window for the pop up.

```
'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-data-dir=tmpdir --incognito
```

I see the pdf download link in the pop window. But it is not clear how to PDF download URL is derived from the original webpage.

Can anybody show me how to figure out the way the PDF download URL is derived from the original webpage? Thanks.

Comment: The URL is already present in the original page. Inspect the download element and you'll see it in `data-popup` attribute that contains a relative URL. To obtain the full URL add the site's origin e.g. `https://www.ingentaconnect.com`

Comment: It's there in wget response. BTW a headless browser will run javascript so even if the attribute was added by a script it'd be still there.